# How to request HERE Map Places lower level categories?

Tags: here-api, here-maps-rest

I'm using the HERE Map Places API.

I can accurately get results in categories like "museums" or "cinema".

I can also get results in shopping malls, but it includes results like grocery stores, butchers. I don't want them. So I have to search by lower-level category. This is available HERE. But I haven't been told how to use it.

how can i take places in this url : https://developer.here.com/documentation/places/dev_guide/topics/place_categories/category-600-shopping.html#category-6100-mall-shopping-complex

Example: 600-6100-0062

Answer (score 0):

Use category param to pass comma separated categories, keep drill to true, e.g. for shopping mall, put category as "clothing-accessories-shop". You can drill down to category id more from the response received.